# What cause glitching in FlatList in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a simple feed where I use FlatList to load posts, and also it has pages that load after it reaches a certain point. For a while, it goes well, loads the pages perfectly but after a few pages, it starts to glitching and sometimes disappear.

I uploaded this GIF about the problem
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPhkg.gif

```js
 <SafeAreaView style={Common.container}>
          <FlatList
            ref={ref => {
              this.flatListRef = ref;
            }}
            ListEmptyComponent={<LandingImage />}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            data={this.state.dataSource}
            onEndReached={()=> handleLoadMore(this)}
            onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
            onRefresh={() => handleRefresh(this)}
            refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
            ItemSeparatorComponent={RenderSeparator}
            renderItem={({item, index}) => this.renderData(item, index)}
            keyExtractor={({item, index}) => index}
          />
          <NewPost
            goCreatePost={() =>
              this.props.navigation.navigate('CreatePost', {
                edit: false,
                refresh: () => handleRefresh(this),
                screen: 'Home',
              })
            }
          />
  </SafeAreaView>
```

Comment: increase onEndReachedThreshold

Answer (score 0):

If the existing `renderItem` Components in your list are class-based and are not expected to change when you `handleLoadMore()`, consider having them extend `React.PureComponent` rather than `React.Component`. This allows react to skip re-rendering them as long as they remain shallow-equal to what they were before the render. This is the suggested way to deal with large sets of data that don't internally change or contain variable nested data.